# How to send json object and recieve a response json object Android in single code

Tags: android

I have created an Android Application in that I am using this code to receive json object from server and i need to send json object from android from same android activity what should i do?**strong text**

```
class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Dialog loadingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(anscheck.this, "Please wait",
                "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String result = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                    new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)

            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception squish) {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        loadingDialog.dismiss();
        String s = result.trim();

        {
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can post `JSON` to server using `StringEntity`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `JSONObject` of whatever data you need to post to server and set it as `StringEntity` to your `HttpPost' method call,
below i am providing some reference code,

First Create your JSON data that you need to post i.e like

```
public String loginArray() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("email", uName);
        jsonObject.put("password", password);
    } catch (JSONException exception) {

    }

    UiUtils.showLog(jsonObject.toString());
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

now set it as an `StringEntity` to your `HttpPost` i.e

```
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(loginArray())
```

write this line before or after you set `header`